# Using pandas resample monthly data to yearly data but start from a certain month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I resample monthly data to yearly data but starting from 1st October.

I tried the following as I know using base works for starting at a certain hour of a day but doesnt appear to work for month of the year.

```
df = (df.resample(rule='Y',  base=10).sum().reset_index())
```

Comment: `base` has been deprecated since version 1.1.0: The new arguments that you should use are ‘offset’ or ‘origin’.

Comment: @SeaBean It looks like offset doesn't work when resampling by months/years

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it:

```
offset = pd.DateOffset(months=9) 

df.shift(freq=-offset).resample('YS').sum().shift(freq=offset)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has [anchored offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) available for annual resamples starting at the first of a month.

The anchored offset for annual resampling starting in October is `AS-OCT`. Resampling and summing can be done like this:

```
df.resample("AS-OCT").sum()
```